# What is the (genuine) name for the Gutik hedgehog?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, terminology

Working with non-regular topological semigroups, my collegue Oleg Gutik discovered a special space $H$ which we named *Gutik's hedgehog*. It is homeomorphic to the space
$$H:=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(\tfrac1n,0):n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(\tfrac1n,\tfrac1{nm}):n,m\in\mathbb N\},$$ endowed with the topology $\tau$ consisting of sets $U\subset H$ satisfying the following two conditions:

(1) if $(\frac1n,0)\in U$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $(\frac1n,\frac1{nk})\in U$ for all $k\ge m$;

(2) if $(0,0)\in U$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $(\frac1n,\frac1{nk})\in U$ for all $n\ge m$ and all $k\in\mathbb N$.

It turns out that Gutik's hedgehog is a test space for regularity in the class of first-countable Hausdorff spaces.

**Theorem.** *A first-countable Hausdorff space is regular if and only if it contains no topological copies of the Gutik hedgehog.*

Because of this fundamental role in testing regularity, I admit that Gutik's hedgehog is known in topology under some different name. I would be grateful for any information in this respect.

**Remark 1.** The Gutik's hedgehog resembles (but is not equal to) the non-regular space of Smirnov, see Example 64 in "Counterexamples in Topology".

Comment: Whatever other name there might be, I prefer "Gutik's hedgehog".

Comment: I also like the hedgehog name. But as a topological space, what is the difference between the Gutik hedgehog and $\omega^2+1$? Unless I've misunderstood, it seems that you have a convergent sequence of convergent sequences, just like $\omega^2+1$.

Comment: According to the theorem, Gutik's hedgehog is not regular, unllike $\omega^2+1$ which is compact Haudsorff.  So we need more explanation of the topology $\tau$ I guess.

Comment: Hmm, it looks more like a porcupine to me.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The difference between the topology of $H$ and the topology of $\omega^2+1$ is that the set $\{(0,0\}\cup\{(\frac1n,\frac1{nm}):n,m\in\mathbb N\}$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $H$ but not in $\omega^2+1$. So, indeed, the Gutik hedgehog is a converent sequence of convergent sequences but the limit points of these convergent sequences do not converge to the central point $(0,0)$  of the hedgehog. Because of that $H$ is not regular.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Porcupine is also a good term. But at least in our country porcupins are not so known as hedgehogs which really live in our forests and gardens.

Comment: My thought was that a hedgehog, facing to the left, has a maximum around halfway. But a porcupine is closer to monotone increasing.

Comment: By the way, the Gutik hedgehog is not regular but is locally regular (=each point has a neighborhood, which is a regular space).

Comment: Difference between hedgehog and porcupine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzKCu9dUcOw.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I rest my case!

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins and Jeremy Rickard Thank you for the explanation of the difference. Knowing Gutik personally (https://plus.google.com/photos/111660746714595792453/album/6171642551038225265/6173827770530836530) I agree that "Gutik porcupine" can be more appropriate name (moreover that the limit points of the spins do not converge to the central point).

Comment: Please keep it as hedgehog. I have already told my Frosya that she has a famous relative in mathematics.

Comment: @NikWeaver If you can link to a picture of Frosya looking triangular, then I will happily withdraw my suggestion.

Comment: @JeremyRickard [I can't deny her a chance at stardom.](https://imgur.com/a/yXaf1)

Comment: Where can I read a proof of the theorem mentioned in the question? Are there more examples of such test spaces?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I do not know. This theorem can easily be proved as an exercise.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Concerning other "test" theorems, there exists, for example, a test space for first-countable spaces, which are not locally countably compact. It is the subset $L=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(\frac1n,\frac1{nm}):n,m\in\mathbb N\}$ of the Euclidean plane. A first-countable regular space $X$ is locally countably compact if and only if $X$ contains no closed subspaces, homeomorphic to $L$. If I remember correctly, the test space $L$ was mentioned in  van Douwen's survey paper in Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology.

Answer (score 3):

Searching Steen & Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology* for "Hausdorff, separable, not regular" I found this example.  Is that it?

This is Example 79, page 97.

> **Irregular Lattice Topology**
>   Let $A = \{(i,k) : 0 < i,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $B = \{(i,0) : i \geq 0\}$ and $X = A \cup B$. Declare each point of $A$ to be open. Let the set of all $U_n((i,0)) = \{(i,k) : k=0$ or $k \geq n\}$ form a local basis at any point with $i \neq 0$ and the set of all $V_n = \{(i,k) : i=k=0$ or $i,k\geq n\}$ be a local basis at $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is almost what is necessary, except for the definition of $V_n$. In the Gutik hedgehog $V_n=\{(i,k):i=k=0$ or $i\ge n\}$. The Gutik hedgehog is homeomorphic to the subspace $\{(0,0\}\cup\{(i,0):i\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(i,k):0<i\le k\}$ of $A$.

Comment: So is this $X$ homeomorphic to $H$ anyway?

Comment: Probably not: the regularization of Guik's hedgehog (or Gutik's porcupine) is compact but the regularization of $A$ is not.